# How to apply Style Css in mvc foreach loop

Tags: c#, razor

I'm new in asp.net mvc and My problem is, I want to conditionally add a CSS background-color to a set of table rows, based on BILL-AMOUNT = 0.00 i have code like this

> @model IEnumerable

**View**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNo)</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px; display: none;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArrDate)</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)</td>
            <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Refund)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)</td>    
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: somthing like :       Controller                                                          List<UserMaster> user = new List<UserMaster>();                          return View(bk);                                                                                     model :                                                                                               @model IEnumerable<PinkPearl.Models.GenerateTicket_Details>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally change CSS class in Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785166/conditionally-change-css-class-in-razor-view)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do an inline style with asp.net mvc 3 razor in a html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481412/how-to-do-an-inline-style-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-in-a-html-helper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a class:

```
.tr-zero {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

You can add the class conditionally like this:

```
<tr@(item.TotalAmount == 0 ? " class=\"tr-zero\"" : string.Empty)>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
          @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
              <tr bgcolor='@(item.AMOUNT==0? "#FFF":"#EEE")'>
              <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNo)</td>
               <td style="padding-left: 12px; display: none;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</td>
               <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArrDate)</td>
               <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)</td>
               <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Refund)</td>
               <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)</td>    
                    </tr>
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
          <tr style="background-color:@(Convert.ToInt32(item.TotalAmount) == 0?"RedColor":"GreenColor")">
          <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNo)</td>
           <td style="padding-left: 12px; display: none;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</td>
           <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ArrDate)</td>
           <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.quantity)</td>
           <td style="padding-left: 12px;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</td>
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Refund)</td>
           <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalAmount)</td>    
          </tr>
         }
    </tbody>
```